# How to refactor operation for list<object>/object?

Tags: c#, refactoring

I'm working on kind of mapper which use `System.Reflection`, and in one case I have possibilities to have list of objects or normal object in my value, and make some logic with it.

**It looks like this more less:**

```
if (myValue is IList) {
    foreach (var value in myValue) {
        ...
        DoSth(value);
        ...
    }
} else {
    ...
    DoSth(myValue);
    ...
}
```

and I have no concept to refactor it, and don't duplicate code (`DoSth()` in this case). Is there some way to do this better?

Comment: I would not call the two calls to `DoSth()` "duplicated code". I see your code ok.

Comment: I don't see the problem. Calling methods multiple times is not what you call *duplicate code*. If you define it so, you shouldn't be calling any method twice, that defeats the whole point of methods. *Duplicate code* is some piece of code repeated in more than one method.

Comment: What do you want to do if `myValue` is a list, but one of its *elements* is also a list?

Comment: It was only an example there are some other logic instead of this one function calling. @JonSkeet I know it could be an issue but it's not possible problem in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If the likely tree is relatively short, you could do something like:

```
void Process(object myValue) {
    if(myValue is IList) {
        foreach(object child in (IList)myValue) {
            Process(child);
        }
        return;
    }
    ...
    DoSth(myValue);
    ...
}
```

If the tree is deep, you can use a stack or queue object (depending on depth-first vs bredth-first) to prevent overflow exceptions from stack-dives.

Note also that *recursion* is a problem here; for example, consider:

```
List<object> evil = new List<object>();
evil.Add(evil); // tempting to add a .Beget() extension method here
Process(evil);
```